# $_SESSION in zend not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to zend framework and I would like to use $_SESSION, but after I start the session using session_start and store a session variable, I am not able to access that variable on another page.

**I know that we can use Zend session namespace but for some reason I would like to stick to $_SESSION.**

```
in controller 1 ->
session_start();
$_SESSION['uid']=$this->_user_id;

in controller 2
session_start();
echo 'this is test comment for session '.$_SESSION['uid'];
```

***Output in view of controller2***

this is the test comment for session

Answer (score 2):

you need to go to the config/autoload/global.php and add session configuration there if it is not:

```
'session' => array(
    'config' => array(
        'class' => 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig',
        'options' => array(
            'name' => 'myapp',
        ),
    ),
    'storage' => 'Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage',
    'validators' => array(
        'Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr',
        'Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent',
    ),
),
```

you don't need to use `session_start()` at all. Then you can set or read sessions without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to access the Session directly? That's all handled by Zend Framework. Please use the Session Manager (http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.manager.html) instead. It provides an abstraction layer.